# Combine several values from text file to one value in postgresql database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I need to copy the content of a textfile (not csv) into a Postgres/Postgis database with a simple sql script.

The textfile looks like

```
#date value
2007 11 29 9 29 14.830 4.1
2007 12 7 21 46 25.560 5.3
```

So the date is **compound by 6 values** (year, month, day, hour, minute, second). I have one `timestamp` field in my DB where the date should be stored (as **one single value**).

I know I can use the `COPY` command to copy each column value of the file to a column value in the database,

```
COPY myDb FROM myValues.txt;
```

but I need to combine several values from the text file to one value in the database.

Sorry if the question has already been asked, I don't really know how to search for this as I just started with sql.

Comment: Create an intermediate (aka "staging") table that has one column for each of the CSV "fields", insert the data into that intermediate table, then use SQL to combine the 6 values to a proper timestamp and insert/update that into the real table

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think about a temporary database - that did the trick!